# How to make the closing quote mark follow the text?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to design a quoting text, but I've faced a problem which is that my closing quote mark doesn't follow the text when I shrink the viewport's window width, so how can I make it do that?

Thank you,

**The code:**

```css
blockquote {
  position : relative;
  }
blockquote p:before { 
  content     : "\201C";
  font-weight : bold;
  font-size   :4.44rem;
  color       :#e48c3e;
  position    : absolute; 
  top         : -33px;
  left        : -40px;
  font-family : 'Playfair Display SC', serif;
  }
blockquote p:after { 
  content     : "\201D";
  font-weight : bold;
  font-size   :4.44rem;
  color       :#e48c3e;
  position    : absolute; 
  bottom      : -58px;
  right       : -38px;
  font-family : 'Playfair Display SC', serif;
  }
```

**The output:**

[image: description]

[image: description]

Comment: Add the HTML part of this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: By 'follow the text' do you mean the closing quote should be right next to the end of 'aliqua'?

Comment: @AHaworth yes exactly.

Comment: How is the css for `<p>` ? why don't you want to add the complete HTML / CSS part of this ?

Comment: @MisterJojo it's very clear, it's <blockquote> tag followed by the <p> tag, it's obvious in the images, and I want the closing quote mark to follow the last word in my paragraph whatever its block has been shrunk.

Comment: What is the styling of the p element?

Comment: `p{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 1rem;
}`
rem is 16px par default @AHaworth

Comment: I had not asked you before what was the **css of `<p>`** ?

Comment: @MisterJojo Sorry I thought that you've asked for the Html of <p>, so here you are now you have it.

Comment: @MisterJojo Anything else?

Comment: you have `p{text-align: justify` and also `blockquote p:after{position: absolute` it is logic that the final quote is at the end of the `p` occupancy rectangle

Comment: @MisterJojo excellent, and this is actually what I'm looking to solve and change please.

Comment: I don't understand you want me to remove the `text-align: justify` and `position: absolute ... and more` for you?

Comment: @MisterJojo could you post your solution so that we can see.

Comment: I can't do that, because you haven't put here a code that I can reproduce on my side as I asked you and recommended it here when we ask this kind of question

Comment: I have a method which removes the p tag. Is that acceptable? I would still urge you to put your code into a working snippet into your question rather than have these long drawn-out bit by bit releasing of code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you have shared, just replace the position with margin (adjust according to your needs) and it will solve your problem, and or if it doesn't share the complete code

**CSS**

```
.p {
        font-size: 43px;
     }
              .p:before { 
             content: "12";
             font-weight: bold;
             font-size:2rem;
             color:#e48c3e;
             margin: 0;
             font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;
         }
         .p:after { 
             content: "32";
             font-weight: bold;
             font-size:2rem;
             color:#e48c3e;
             margin: 12px;
             font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier to know HTML and how the font is set on `:root` to see if there's a global default font and the `font-size` `body` since that's what the `rem` bases itself on.

But I believe your main problem is that your `<p>` is the parent of the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements so the `<p>` should have `position: relative`. Also, it'd be much more responsive if the lengths were relative units (ex. percentage, em, rem, ch) instead of an absolute value like px.

In the example below I guessed at the `:root` and `body` (don't even know if they exist in your code). The `<q>` replaces `<p>` and `<p>` is wrapped around paragraphs.

```css
:root {
  font: 2ch/1 'Segoe UI'
}

body {
  font-size: 2ch
}

q {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

blockquote q:before {
  content: "\201C";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4.44rem;
  color: #e48c3e;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.5ch;
  left: -1ch;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;
}

blockquote q:after {
  content: "\201D";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 4.44rem;
  color: #e48c3e;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1.25ch;
  right: -1ch;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display SC', serif;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <q>
<p>Babybel cheeseburger manchego. Swiss cheeseburger fromage cream cheese mascarpone cheese on toast jarlsberg pepper jack. Cream cheese cheese and wine ricotta manchego cheesy feet pepper jack emmental bocconcini. Cauliflower cheese rubber cheese croque monsieur port-salut mozzarella stinking bishop red leicester.</p>

<p>Smelly cheese mozzarella cheese triangles. Emmental chalk and cheese fondue monterey jack cut the cheese cow cheese and biscuits cauliflower cheese. Croque monsieur queso melted cheese brie monterey jack fromage frais ricotta. Cheese bocconcini. Cut the cheese.</p>
</q>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem, the closing quote mark still follows the block, but instead, I want it to follow the last word in my paragraph whatever the block has been shrunk.

Comment: It's funny how you believe you can get a conciese and correct answer when 1. You haven't provided a complete answer. 2. What is provided is not completely clear. ex. there are 2 images: 1st image has the quotes close to the end of the text 2nd image has quotes far from the end of the text. The images have a title: "output"...ok so is this the output you want or the output you are getting and don't want? Also, now that you have described what you want a little more clearer (albiet rudely), it seems to me that you want the first image and not the 2nd image. If you ask a half-assed question..

Comment: I'm reading my past comment and laughing, sorry if you've felt it to be rude, however, I've mentioned everything in detail in the description above, my problem is when I shrink the viewport window my closing quote doesn't follow my last word in my paragraph as the second image shows. I hope that this clarify my problem to you.

Comment: I'm laughing too, all I see is an unanswerable question because the OP can't take the time to provide what's been asked by far better programmers than you or I.  Good luck.